# MongoDB to improve complex filter based queries?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, query-optimization, database-performance

I am in the process of bootstrapping a SaaS project and have come across a performance bottleneck that I'm struggling to overcome:

I have a multi-tenant application where each tenant (referred to as 'customer') can have their own set of 'end_customers'. The number of end customers per customer averages around 3,000 to 5,000, but could be as high as 300k.

Each customer can create up to 30 custom fields for their end customers, which can be of different data types (text, number, date, or a constrained text value). The data is currently stored in a MariaDB database.

The end_customer_field table is basically a key-value lookup without any indexes, and value is stored as varchar(255).

I'm trying to allow my customers to perform dynamic filter queries on their end customers. These queries involve joining the end_customer table with the end_customer_field table up to 30 times, and may require type conversion from varchar to number or date. I've implemented a variety of logical comparison operators based on the data type. However, complex filters are running for several minutes and then timing out, which is not suitable for a production environment.

I've been considering different solutions:

- Reducing the number of allowed search criteria.
- Altering the data storage, such as using multiple columns for
  different data types in the end_customer_field table or splitting it
  into separate tables per data type.
- Switching to a different type of database.

The third point is where I'm seeking help. I don't have any prior experience with NoSQL databases, but I've heard they might be more efficient for this kind of use case. I'm considering MongoDB, but I'm not sure if it's the right choice or how to effectively structure my data in it.

Here are my questions:

- Would a NoSQL database like MongoDB be a good fit for this scenario?
- How could I structure my data in MongoDB (or another NoSQL database)
  to handle these dynamic filter queries efficiently?
- Are there any other solutions or strategies that could help solve my
  performance issues?

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This could be as simple as a MongoDB doc that looks like this:  `{tenant:"A", customer:"X1", userdef: { whatever }`.   That's it.  No JOINs.
A single multipart Index on `tenant+customer` would get you to the userdef polymorphic field very quickly.   The question becomes is indexing necessary on the userdef fields?   I'd start with no.  Also: with MongoDB, no limit to the userdef shape.  30 fields, 60 fields, fields of arrays, anything.

Comment: So how would I then mix my mariadb relational database with using MongoDB? could I have the tenant data in mariadb, and just the field in MongoDB?

Comment: Sure.   The setup is the same as my comment above.   Note there's no other tenant info, just the key.   If it is not too disruptive, I'd just move everything into MongoDB.  I will bet there are fields in the MariaDB tables for tenant and customer that might be more fluidly modeled in MongoDB rich shapes. Example: an array of address structures instead of address_1, address_2, etc.